# Wordpress getting category of images without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I've been working on a project for a photographer.

I'm trying to make a category list for the photos.
Like this:
[Category of photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcHQZ.png)

But the problem is when I click on a category it automatically refreshes the website, that's not what I want. I want to refresh the photos, not the website.

I've tried to use preventDefault in Javascript but it doesn't work.

How do I have to fix this?

-- Javascript --

```
function getClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    var getCategory = document.querySelectorAll(".cat a");
    for(var i = 0, ilen = getCategory.length; i < ilen; i++) {
        getCategory[i].addEventListener("click", getClick);
    }
```

-- HTML --

```html
<div class="cat">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="recent" href="?assignement=recent">RECENT</a></li>
        <li><a class="all" href="?assignement=all">ALL</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

-- Php Wordpress--

```php
  <?php if($_GET["assignement"] == "recent") : ?>
                <?php
          $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'orderby' => 'date' );
                  global $post;
                  $recent_posts = get_posts($args);
                  foreach($recent_posts as $post) :
                  ?>
                  <?php if( in_category("photos") ) : ?>
                  <div class="grid-item hover-item" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <div class="photo-title">
                      <?php
                        if ( is_single() ) {
                          the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title">', '</h2>' );
                        } else {
                          the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title">', '</h2>' );
                        }
                      ?>
                      <p>by <a href="Michelle">MICHELLE</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <?php add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); ?>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                  </div><!-- grid-item -->
                  <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you

Yawuar.

Comment: I created a file and put the HTML and the JavaScript within a script tag and the click event was prevented like expected. Are you sure the script gets to run after the elements start to exist? Put `console.log(getCategory.length)` at the end of the script and check if it says 0 in the console by doing Ctrl+Shift+L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `preventDefault` likely isn't working because the page has not loaded when you try to add the event listeners, try something like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function() {
    function getClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    
    var getCategory = document.querySelectorAll(".cat a");
    for (var i = 0, ilen = getCategory.length; i < ilen; i++) {
        getCategory[i].addEventListener("click", getClick);
    }
});
```

2. Even if `preventDefault` does work it will simply prevent the page from hitting your PHP. You need to use your event handler to make an AJAX request to the PHP url, and then inject the response into the page. Something similar to:

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
   document.getElementById("your_photos_element").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "your_php_url.php", true);
xhttp.send();
```